# What's the best way to integrate a wordpress blog on my laravel site?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, laravel

I have a ***laravel*** site(app) and I want to put a ***wordpress*** **blog** at `mysitename.com/blog`.

**What's the best way to do it?** Should I *just be following the instructions on wordpress* docs for a normal integration? *Or I should be creating eloquent models* for blog and then proceed somehow with that? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install it in a separate directory in the public directory. They should work fine, not knowing about each other.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a package that allows you to use wordpress as a backend system. The news website "laravel news" made a great thread on the topic.

https://laravel-news.com/wordpress-and-laravel